# iOS 7 - Pass data from SWRevealViewController to RearViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, appdelegate, xcode-storyboard

I'm using the SWRevealViewController to get Sidemenu Functionality.
Now i need to load a large Xml-File at the Startup of my App.

I need to pass the Xml-Content to my TabBarViewController (RearViewController) embedded in a NavigationController.

-> SWRevealViewController -> NavigationController -> TabBarViewController (RearViewController)

Have a look here to my Storyboard-Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ynVa.png

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
      SWRevealViewController *swRevealViewController = (SWRevealViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    }

  return YES;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use delegate method:

```
-(void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position {
    MyTableViewController *tableViewController = (MyTableViewController *)revealController.rearViewController;
    tableViewController.items = stores;
    tableViewController.selectedItemIndexPath = self.self.selectedStoreIndexPath;
}
```

but i don't use TableViewController you need add TableView on ViewController